# Using memory, reserved in boot time, for DMA

Tags: linux, driver, dma, pci

I have some memory, reserved from grub command line (by passing mem=4096m argument), so I have physical address of this memory and it's size. Now I want to use it for DMA with PCIe device. How can I do this?
Thanks in advance for help!